# Is it possible to define a Stan model in terms of an arbitrary posterior function?

Tags: c++, r, bayesian, stan

Is it possible to define a Stan model in terms of an arbitrary posterior function?

I'm thinking something like MCMCPack's MCMCmetrop1R() functionality where the user defines an arbitrary posterior function. I would be fine with digging into the C++ API to do this if there's a good example of how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a manner of speaking, defining an arbitrary posterior distribution is all you can do in the Stan language. But if you are referring specifically to a posterior distribution that is not a composition of distributions that are already defined in Stan, then you can use the `increment_log_prob` function to add terms to the log-posterior, whether they are part of the likelihood of the data or are priors on parameters. See the chapters of the user manual entitled "Custom Probability Functions" and "User-Defined Functions".

There is an [example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/stan-users/4gv3fNCqSNk/4dwmJj1YwbsJ) under the FAQ at the stan-users Google group, although it utilizes the deprecated syntax of manipulating the `lp__` symbol directly instead of using the `increment_log_prob` function to do the same thing. Nowdays the .stan file would be

```
data {
  int<lower=1> N;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> x[N];
}
transformed data {
  real sum_log_x; // calculate this constant only once
  sum_log_x <- 0.0;
  for (i in 1:N)
    sum_log_x <- sum_log_x + log(x[i]);
}
parameters {
  real<lower=0> a;
  real<lower=0> b;
}
model {
  real summands[N];
  // put priors on a and b here if you want

  // log-likelihood
  increment_log_prob(N * (log(a) + log(b)) + (a - 1) * sum_log_x);
  for (i in 1:N) {
    summands[i] <- (b - 1) * log1m(pow(x[i],a)); // log1m(y) := log(1 - y)
  }
  increment_log_prob(summands);
}
```

Comment: can you guys show a simple example? i think there are others out there that aren't super familiar with the codebase but would be interested in this as an end user for modeling purposes.

Comment: thanks for the example - is there a C++ example where the LL is defined in C++ code (ie doing arbitrary calculations outside of stan-defined functions)?

Comment: I don't think the C++ API is considered stable yet, although it is useable. Assuming that you could get the C++ code to compile without first parsing the Stan code, then writing a C++ function to manipulate the `lp__` symbol would be easy. If you just save the above example to a .stan file to your hard disk and then go to the directory where you downloaded CmdStan and type `make /path/to/Stanfile` without the .stan extension then you can look at the generated C++ code in the same directory as your .stan file.